# Приложение остановлено из-за исключения (Exception at 0x7ff6a54ef811)

Tags: c++, qt, исключения

Не могу даже понять в какой строчки кода возникает исключение :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда отлаживаю вылетает не в моём class QMap, а библиотеке контейнеров на строчке:

```
inline bool isEmpty() const { return d->size == 0; }
```

c QMap мой код такой :

ViewshedGeoElement.h

```
QMap <QString, QMap <Esri::ArcGISRuntime::OrbitGeoElementCameraController* ,Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Graphic*>> m_ModelControllerGraphic;
```

ViewshedGeoElement.cpp

```
bool ViewshedGeoElement::createGraphic3D(const double x, const double y, const double z, QString PathModel, QString NameModel, const double w, const double h, const double Depth)
{

    if (!missionReady())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Esri::ArcGISRuntime::ModelSceneSymbol* m_model3d = nullptr;
    Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Graphic* m_graphic3d = nullptr;
    Esri::ArcGISRuntime::OrbitGeoElementCameraController* m_followingController = nullptr;
    const QString dataPath = QQmlProperty::read(this, "dataPath").toString();

    // create the ModelSceneSymbol to be animated in the 3d view
    if (!m_model3d)
        m_model3d = new ModelSceneSymbol(QUrl(dataPath + PathModel), 10.0f, this);

    // get the mission data for the frame
    const MissionData::DataPoint& dp = m_missionData->dataAt(missionFrame());

    if (!m_graphic3d)
    {
        // create a graphic using the model symbol
        m_graphic3d = new Graphic(dp.m_pos, m_model3d, this);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(HEADING, dp.m_heading);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(PITCH, dp.m_pitch);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->insertAttribute(ROLL, dp.m_roll);

        // add the graphic to the graphics overlay
        m_sceneView->graphicsOverlays()->at(0)->graphics()->append(m_graphic3d);

        // create the camera controller to follow the graphic
        m_followingController = new OrbitGeoElementCameraController(m_graphic3d, 500, this);
        m_sceneView->setCameraController(m_followingController);
    }
    else
    {
        // update existing graphic's geometry and attributes
        m_graphic3d->setGeometry(dp.m_pos);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->replaceAttribute(HEADING, dp.m_heading);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->replaceAttribute(PITCH, dp.m_pitch);
        m_graphic3d->attributes()->replaceAttribute(ROLL, dp.m_roll);
    }

    QMap <Esri::ArcGISRuntime::OrbitGeoElementCameraController* ,Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Graphic*> m_ControllerGraphic;
    m_ControllerGraphic.insert(m_followingController,m_graphic3d);
    m_ModelControllerGraphic.insert(NameModel,m_ControllerGraphic);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Исключение возникало из-за пустых значений, которые я пытался положить в QMap.
Cледующая проверка позволяет избежать этого:

```
if( !m_followingController && !m_graphic3d ) return false;
QMap <Esri::ArcGISRuntime::OrbitGeoElementCameraController* ,Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Graphic*> m_ControllerGraphic;
m_ControllerGraphic.insert(m_followingController,m_graphic3d);
if( m_ModelControllerGraphic.contains(NameModel) ) {
    //  #TODO сделать что то если модель уже была в списке
}else {
    m_ModelControllerGraphic.insert(NameModel,m_ControllerGraphic);
}
```